# allow page access only for admin user Django

Tags: python, django

So I need to allow page access only for admin user in Django, I'm trying this piece of code to use in app views.py, but its not working well..

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def index(request):
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        return redirect('https://xx.com')
    return render(request, 'scan_debug/index.html')
```

Comment: What is not working well?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [user_passes_test](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) decorator:

Then you can create an `admin_check` method like so:

```
def admin_check(user):
   return user.is_superuser
```

Pass the `admin_check` method to the decorator like so:

```
@user_passes_test(admin_check)
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for this, i had issue with caching... I just needed to restart server